# Android WebView no selection color

Tags: android, facebook, colors, webview, selector

In my application I have a webView that contains the FB like button.
JS is enabled to get redirected.
Now my problem is, I want to get rid of the orange selector.
I know this can be done by css, but where do I put my Css file , and how to apply it to my webView?
or is there a other way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it!

```
    webView.setFocusable(false);
```